# How to write jasmine unit test for primeng datatables?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, primeng

Could any one of you help me out on how to write unit test for (onRowSelect) event of primeng datatable. In my scenario i am trying to navigate to another component when user clicked on row.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I do unit testing for onRowClick with PromeNG datatable. It should be very similar to onRowSelect.

You can look at component and its unit test at my github repo: https://github.com/ipassynk/ristorante-fornello/tree/master/src/app/menu

```
it('should call showDetails on row click', async(() => {
  const spy = spyOn(comp, 'showDetails');
   fixture.detectChanges();

  const cell = debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.ui-datatable-odd .ui-cell-data'))[0];
  cell.nativeElement.click();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
}));
```